# Error Level in Exception

Tags: c#, exception

I am handling errors using `IErrorHandler` in `WCF REST`. I need to log class name, method name, line number, error code etc. and i find out the soultions to all this.

But I am thinking any possibility or options to get 1ErrorLevel1 like windows event viewer. Eg: Warning, Information, Error.

Actually if I do like this my applciation exceptions can be put as Information. This can be work simple create an custom Exception class.

1. But my question is for other exceptions (other than my application exceptions) any option to get this level based on the error. I don't need to set this level for other types of erros.
2. Actually i am logging the exception in HandleError event. Now i am just throw my exceptions as applicationexception.

Just see my Service method code below:

```
        if(!long.TryParse("534543534", out value))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Input is Not Valid!!!");
        }
```

So in my error handling i got this as application exception. Here i dont knwo this is because of FormatException, Overflow Exception, ArgumentNullException. How i handle this. I can add the original exception as innerexception but need to wrap try..catch in each service method to get the exception. Is this good practice when i have the `IErrorHandler` methods. Please suggest good approach for this

Comment: If you are going to throw an exception when TryParse() fails then there is no point in using TryParse.  Just use Parse() and you'll automatically get the appropriate exception.

Comment: k so in my service methods also no need to use try ..catch. simple use parse like that so error is populated to the handler. Actually i need to separate the errors like application and sql connection / network related. Because i need to log the errors in db table. See my question related to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717073/xception-handling-for-database-connection-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET, an exception is a severe error that interrupts the process of your application. The framework does (for the most part) not provide an error level as all exceptions are basically errors. If an exception is thrown, this always means that there is an error that the application cannot continue with.

If you want to discern between the exception types and write some as informational messages or warnings to your log, you'd have to inspect the exceptions in your error handler, e.g. by code similar to this:

```
public class MyErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    // ...
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, TraceLevel> _exceptionTraceLevelMappings;

    static MyErrorHandler()
    {
        _exceptionTraceLevelMappings = new Dictionary<Type, TraceLevel>();
        _exceptionTraceLevelMappings.Add(typeof(ApplicationException), TraceLevel.Information);
        _exceptionTraceLevelMappings.Add(typeof(ArgumentException), TraceLevel.Warning);
    }

    private static TraceLevel GetLevelByExceptionType(Type exType)
    {
        // You might want to add a more sophisticated approach here (e.g. for base classes)
        if (_exceptionTraceLevelMappings.ContainsKey(exType))
            return _exceptionTraceLevelMappings[exType];
        return TraceLevel.Error;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Based upon the comments, you want to discern between errors that are raised to coding mistakes and input data validation errors. In this case, you'd need to implement a CustomException type and use TryParse to validate input data:

```
public class MyValidationException : Exception
{
    public MyValidationException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    // A custom exceptions needs several constructors, so add them also
}
```

In your service code, you'd use TryParse as in your sample:

```
if(!long.TryParse("534543534", out value))
{
    throw new MyValidationException("Input is Not Valid!!!");
}
```

In the mapping dictionary, you can register your exception type and assign TraceLevel.Information:

```
// ...
_exceptionTraceLevelMappings.Add(typeof(MyValidationException), TraceLevel.Information);
// ...
```

Comment: @Akhil: As for the Framework exceptions, I'd propose to just let them happen in the service methods and not handle them there. If there is an error, an exception is thrown, whether there is a catch-block or not. If you catch the exceptions, they will not be handed to your error handler. In the error handler you can take care of them. However, as you can hardly know any exception type that might be thrown in your application, you are not able to add each type to the dictionary. Therefore, my approach returns TraceLevel.Error if an exception type is not contained in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks so i can avoid try..catch also in service methods. And use try..catch in handle error event of IErrorHandler so that any logging related errors also handled. Like you told custom error type can be used for including ErrorLevel and myown errorcode. I think this is good practice. please suggest. Also onething. Since i using uriTemplate in my service i am using string for all parameters. So how i seperate that user is giving wrong parameter format and the code gives format exception due to coding error

Comment: @Akhil: Typically, you don't need ErrorLevel or error code in your own exceptions as any exception breaks application flow and therefore is a severe error. Also, the framework does not discern between exceptions because of input data and exceptions because of coding errors. A FormatException can be caused by both, but only analysis of the error can show the reason. So if you want to raise and handle input data validation errors differently, use TryParse and throw a custom exception type that you can handle differently in your ErrorHandler.

Comment: Can you please guide me in which case i give true / false as return in handleerror event. if i put true it should abort the session. In general i put the value as true. In which case it needs false so that the session and instance context is aborted

Comment: @Akhil: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.handleerror(v=vs.110).aspx says that you should return false by default. False means to abort the session and instance context, true for the opposite. So I think you need to invert your return value. I'd also tend to return false by default; true only if there is a strong reason for it and if you are 100% sure that the session and instance context is still valid after the exception. If you do not use sessions and a special instance context, just return false.

Comment: I have one more confusion when implementing this concept. This is in REST service. So custom exception can be derived from Exception  class? so that i can use the base properties in my custom error. Because most custom errors in wcf rest simply create a contract and use that instead of inherit from Exception

Comment: @Akhil: if you want to create custom exceptions, you have to derive them from the `Exception` class. In a REST service, you might also decide to not throw an exception (and therefore have no need to create a custom one) but to set the return status code accordingly (e.g. 404 Not Found, 500 Internal Server Error). This will not raise an exception and therefore not invoke the IErrorHandler.